# npm global package(ember-cli) install as devDependency in project

Tags: npm, ember-cli

If I `npm install -g ember-cli@2.7.0`, then in my project, if I do `npm install --save-dev ember-cli@2.7.0`, shouldn't the global `ember-cli` be copied over to my project right away, and just bump up version number in package.json?

Am I right?

Comment: Are you finding any exceptions??

Answer (score 0):

Technically it will use the cached version (in the `npm_cache` folder) to do the install, not the copy that you installed globally.  As for the version number, it *should* update your `package.json` file to `"ember-cli": "^2.7.0"`